# Pandas: How to structure row-wise apply which requires previous output as input

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have to compute some `newValue` for each row. `newValue` is the solution to a nonlinear equation in `df.col1, df.col2`. I decided to implement this as a row-wise `df.apply()`.

However, I would like to take the result from the previous row, and use it as a guess for the optimization for the next row. I am clueless on how to set that up. Following is my rough code sketch, and as you can see, I don't know how to provide `guess` to `getFlow()`.

```
# this function does some computation given a row
def getFlow(row, guess = False):
    # define a residual to minimize
    def flowResidual(col1, col2):
        # here would be some code
        return np.abs(doSomeCalculationsAndCreateResidual(col1, col2))
    if guess == False:
        guess = 0.1
    inflowRate = optimize.fmin(flowResidual, guess, args=(row.col1, row.col2))
# I have some dataframe df
df['newValue'] = df.apply(getFlow, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a global variable to keep track of the guess, but probably much cleaner to loop explicitly, as in pseudo-code below.

```
ans = np.zeros(len(df))

for i, (col1, col2) in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False)):
    ...
    if i == 0:
        guess = 0.1
    else:
        guess = ans[i-1]
    ans[i] = optimize(...)

df['newValue'] = ans
```